# Generic Inheritance clarification on downcasting

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a generic interface hierarchy which describes some controllers for other generic types, and I'm having trouble clarifying in my mind why a particular casting scenario is not valid.

Simplified code is as follows;

```
// 'DTO' interfaces
public interface IBase
{ }

public interface IDerived : IBase
{ }


// 'DTOs'
public class Base : IBase
{ }

public class Derived : Base, IDerived
{ }


// controller interfaces
public interface IBaseController<T> where T : class, IBase
{ }

public interface IDerivedController : IBaseController<IDerived>
{ }


// controllers
public class BaseController<T> : IBaseController<T>
    where T : class, IBase
{ }

public class DerivedController : BaseController<IDerived>, IDerivedController
{ }
```

Now, the situation I'm having trouble with is this;

```
IDerivedController x = new DerivedController();
bool is1 = x is IDerivedController;   // true
bool is2 = x is IBaseController<IDerived>; // true
bool is3 = x is IBaseController<IBase>; // false ???
```

The final line is where my confusion lies. The controller interfaces associate correctly, and the 'DTOs'. But not both together... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386 for info on variant generic interfaces, which is the heart of what you're asking.  You must declare that an `IBaseController<IDerived>` can in fact be used as an `IBaseController<IBase>` in order for it to be used as such.

For the reason for this, consider trying to use a `List<string>` as an `IList<object>` vs trying to use an `IEnumerable<string>` as an `IEnumerable<object>`.  The `IEnumerable` conversion is ok because you can use the items as `object`s without any problems, but you can't add any `object` to a `List<string>`, because then it would contain something besides `string`s.

If you change it to `public interface IBaseController<out T> where T : class, IBase`, then `x is IBaseController<IBase>` becomes `true`.  If the compiler complains that you can't make `T` an `out` parameter, then you can't do the conversion you're looking to do (unless you change the interface to make it compatible).

Comment: Rightio, thanks for that. That clears it up! Sadly, I can't make my type covariant here so will have to find another approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Think what would that mean if you had a collection of shapes: is a `Collection<Triagle>` the same as (*is-a*) `Collection<Shape>`?  If it would be than we could put any shapes into our collection of triangles.  OTOH if `Collection<Shape>` was (*is-a*) `Collection<Triangle>`, then we could put a `Square` in there (after all, it is a collection of shapes), and expect to get only `Triangle`s out.

Similar is true for your `BaseController<Iderived>`

Answer (score 1):

This is because `IBaseController` is not [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). You could make it covariant by declaring it like this:

```
public interface IBaseController<out T> where T : class, IBase
{
}
```

But then `T` could only be used in an output position.

Imagine your interface looks like this:

```
public interface IBaseController<T> where T : class, IBase
{
    void DoSomething(T x);
}
```

In `IBaseController<IDerived>`, the method signature would be:

```
void Something(IDerived x)
```

Now, if `IBaseController<IDerived>` were assignable to `IBaseController<IBase>`, you could do something like this:

```
public class Derived2 : Base
{ }


IDerivedController x = ...
IBaseController<IBase> y = x;
y.DoSomething(new Derived2()); // oops! Derived2 doesn't implement IDerived
```